# get struts2 <s:url> value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I use struts2  to generate action url, something likes:

```
<s:url id="response_url" action="submitReponse" />
```

How can I get the generate action url in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use struts2  [jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)